# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component show in react chat app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, material-ui

Issues as like

```
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
**More Vital Issue/User Msg:**
react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the <WithStyles(ForwardRef(AppBar))> component:
```

**Folder Structure**
[React Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZDxO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Functional components are different from classes
When you use functional components (functions) you can use all the react hooks except lifecycle hooks like componentDidMount
While in class components you can use life cycle hooks but not other react hooks like(useState())

In other to use the react hooks change your class components to a functional one